# How to filter the rows in the dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the data frame

```
big = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A', 'A', 'A','A', 'B','B','C','D','D', 'D'], 'animal': ['ALL other', 'cat','rabbit', 'dog', 'rabbit','ALL other', 'ALL', 'ALL other', 'dog','cat']})
big
        group   animal
0   A   ALL other
1   A   cat
2   A   rabbit
3   A   dog
4   B   rabbit
5   B   ALL other
6   C   ALL
7   D   ALL other
8   D   dog
9   D   cat
```

the rule is that if rabbit in the group then pick out the group, if the animal is 'ALL' then pick all and regard it as rabbit, if there is no rabbit in the group then pick 'ALL other' and regard it as rabbit.

The small data frame is below

```
    group   animal
0   A   rabbit
1   B   rabbit
2   C   ALL
3   D   ALL other
```

Comment: is this a homework? if yes , show us what have you tried so far

Comment: Try using .loc method to filter the rows in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

First filter the DataFrame to only keep rabbit/ALL/ALL other, then take advantage of the fact that rabbit is sorted after ALL in lexicographic order to get a [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
m = big['animal'].isin(['rabbit', 'ALL', 'ALL other'])

big[m].groupby('group', as_index=False).max()
```

For a generic approach, make "animal" an ordered `Categorical` and you will be able to choose any custom order.

Output:

```
  group     animal
0     A     rabbit
1     B     rabbit
2     C        ALL
3     D  ALL other
```

Comment: thanks for it, can I ask how to keep the sequence of the rows?  Found that it will be out of order after using groupby.max()

Comment: Add `sort=False` as parameter to `groupby`